# system.invalidoperationexception: collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. Need ideas?

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error from my C# Emulator,

```
Error en thread Room cycle task for room 1: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at Mercury.HabboHotel.Rooms.RoomManager.UnloadRoom(Room Room) in                        xampp\Emulator\HabboHotel\Rooms\RoomManager.cs:line 629
at Mercury.HabboHotel.Rooms.Room.ProcessRoom() in c:\xampp\Emulator\HabboHotel\Rooms\Room.cs:line 807
```

Quick explanation, this emulator is for a flash game. The code it's referring too is such. RoomManager.cs line 629;

```
lock (Room.RoomChat)
            {
                foreach (Chatlog current2 in Room.RoomChat)
                {
                    current2.Save(Room.RoomId);
                }
            }
            Room.Destroy();
```

It's the foreach line. Room.cs line 807,

```
if (this.IdleTime >= 60/* && usersQueueToEnter.Count == 0*/)
                    {
                        MercuryEnvironment.GetGame().GetRoomManager().UnloadRoom(this);
                        mIsIdle = false;
                        return;
                    }
```

It's the MercuryEnvironment.GetGame() Line to be exact. Basically, the first void I showed is meant to be saving a room chatlog and then 'destroying' the room which is just meaning no one is in it. The second part refers to an idle timer. If your character goes idle for too long, they update with a little 'Zzz' next to them, after a while they get kicked from the room. So, I'm not sure what is going on with this problem. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What does `current2.Save` look like?

Comment: I'm guessing this has been answered 100 times here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: current2.Save is just `foreach (Chatlog current2 in Room.RoomChat)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove an item from a collection during a foreach.

**Edit**

The exception is been throwing when you remove the 'room' from the collection you are iterating in the foreach. There would be a problem with the internal counter.

As pointed, using Reverse in the foreach might work.

Comment: Oddly enough, you can if you `Reverse` the enumeration. Its hard to say if he is doing that here though. An `Add` can also cause this exception.

Comment: Ok. The Add will have the same impact changing the collection. But what do you mean by "reverse" the enumeration?

Comment: IIRC You can remove items if you do `foreach(var item in collection.Reverse()) { ...  }`. Its really odd.

Comment: There is nothing special about yourCollection.Reverse(), I think. Any operation that copies the whole collection before iterating will work, such as yourCollection.ToList(). (And Reverse() unfortunately makes a copy even if the collection allows indexed access). AFAIK  even OrderBy() will work. But I would suggest explicitely making a copy for iteration before the foreach loop, if you want to modify the list

Comment: Ok, reverse as in going backwards. This way you don't have priblems with the internal count

Comment: Hold on guys, I'm really new to C#, so I'm getting a little confused here. I can provide more code if you'd like?

Comment: I don't think more code is required. You have a foreach loop. In this foreach you call a save routine and pass a "room" to it. This "Room" is the current item in the foreach. Then, inside your save routine, at some point, you are trying to remove the room from the collection (probably the line with the getgame). This is not allowed, because the foreach will lost track from its current item.

Comment: The way to remove an ittem from a collection during a loop is to iterate backwards, as was suggested in the previous comments. So, in your foreach, use the Reverse as was showed.

Comment: You can also use a for looping going from the last index to the first, instead of using a foreach looping.

Comment: Using .Reverse() worked fine amigos :) Feel so silly for not getting it. Like I said, I'm new to the whole C# Emulation.